# CakePHP 2.X Path Based XSS issue

Tags: cakephp, routes, url-routing, xss

I'm having an issue where I've set up a route for pages, however, if you enter in something following the slug you can pass information into the website causing a "Path-Based Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)". For example "/lending-center/"%20qss%3D"QssAttrValue"

```
Router::connect('/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute')
);

Router::connect('/:slug/*',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute')
);
```

What this code should do is route everything to the pages controller, then anything additional should be passed in the $this->params['pass'], instead what I am receiving via a debug of $this->params is

```
params => array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'display',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array(
        (int) 0 => '" qss="QssAttrValue'
    ),
    'slug' => '" qss="QssAttrValue',
    'isAjax' => false
)
```

I'm very confused as to why slug is not being set as lending-center instead of whats showing in the debug output. Thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

Version: CakePHP 2.9

```
class SlugRoute extends CakeRoute {

function parse($url) {
    $params = parent::parse($url);
    if (empty($params)) {
        return false;
    }

    $slugs = Cache::read('page_slugs');
    if (empty($slugs)) {
        App::import('Model', 'Page');
        $Page = new Page();
        $pages = $Page->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('Page.slug'),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
        $slugs = array_flip(Set::extract('/Page/slug', $pages));
        Cache::write('page_slugs', $slugs);
    }

    if (isset($slugs[$params['slug']])) {
        return $params;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

The display function inside the PagesController.php is as follows:

```
public function display($slug = null) { 
    if (!empty($slug)) {
        $this->params['slug'] = $slug;
    }

    if (empty($this->params['slug'])) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Sorry, file not found.'));
    }

    $body_id = strtolower(Inflector::classify($this->name));
    $conditions = array('Page.slug' => $this->params['slug']);
    $result = $this->Page->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));

    if (empty($result['Page']['name'])) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Sorry, file not found.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('result'));
}
```

Comment: You're probably either using an outdated CakePHP version with a bug (please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version), or it's your custom routing class doing something weird which we cannot see (please always include all relevant code).

Comment: @ndm I've updated my original post to include more data.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes configuration miss that `slug` [needs to be passed](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) to controller, and what comes down is that this:

```
public function display($slug = null) { 
    if (!empty($slug)) {
        $this->params['slug'] = $slug;
    }
```

Replaces the named param `slug` with the only passed last arg. I mean that:

```
$slug === '" qss="QssAttrValue'
```

in this case.

If you change routes config to be:

```
Router::connect('/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute', 'pass' => ['slug'])
);

Router::connect('/:slug/*',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute', 'pass' => ['slug'])
);
```

Then the display method arguments will be:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'lending-center',
    (int) 1 => '" qss="QssAttrValue'
)
```